# incrementing a start date by hour until it reaches an end date

Tags: python, datetime

I have date range like this:

```
start_date ='2018-01-01T00:00:00'
end_date ='2018-01-31T23:59:59'
```

Converted it to objects:

```
start_date_object = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
end_date_object = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

I'm trying to write a function that will take the start date and increment it by 1 hour until it reaches the end date like this:

```
def daterange(start,end):
    while start <= end :
        start = start + timedelta(hours=1)
        print

daterange(start_date_object,end_date_object)
```

But currently my output is this:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00
2018-01-01 01:00:00
2018-01-01 01:00:00
```

I expected it to do this

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00
2018-01-01 01:00:00
2018-01-01 02:00:00
...
..
2018-01-31 23:59:59
```

Am I using time delta incorrectly?

Comment: Your `start_date_object` and `end_date_object` are the same.

Comment: fixed a code edit, thanks for catching that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable `end_date_object` using `end_date` rather than `start_date` i.e:

```
end_date_object = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Additionally, to get the `2018-01-31 23:59:59` for the last line you need to use `<` rather than `<=` in your while loop and then subtract 1 second from `start` before printing it one last time outside the while loop:

**Full fixed code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def daterange(start, end):
  while start < end:
    print(start)
    start += timedelta(hours=1)
  print(start - timedelta(seconds=1)) # To get the XX:XX:59:59 for the last line

start_date ='2018-01-01T00:00:00'
end_date ='2018-01-31T23:59:59'

start_date_object = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
end_date_object = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

daterange(start_date_object, end_date_object)
```

**Output:**

```
2018-01-01 01:00:00
2018-01-01 02:00:00
2018-01-01 03:00:00
2018-01-01 04:00:00
2018-01-01 05:00:00
2018-01-01 06:00:00
2018-01-01 07:00:00
2018-01-01 08:00:00
2018-01-01 09:00:00
2018-01-01 10:00:00
.
.
.
2018-01-31 20:00:00
2018-01-31 21:00:00
2018-01-31 22:00:00
2018-01-31 23:00:00
2018-01-31 23:59:59
```

Comment: Ah I didn't catch that I had end_date = start_date. What I did notice running this was this line `2018-01-31 22:00:00 2018-01-31 23:00:00/ 2018-02-01 00:00:00 / 2018-01-31 23:59:59` note the `02-01`. how is that possible in this loop?

Comment: yeah I just ran it, it happens right after 01-31 23:00 then goes to 02-01 00:00 and the last line is 01-31-23:59:59

Comment: I see whats happening.. its tacking on an hour after it passes the < end check. I guess there should be an if statement on the print. But I don't know if that is the best way to do this.

Comment: Fixed it, I was printing after the time delta addition... I think I fixed this bug yesterday but I didn't add it to the answer code cus I copied the results from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` has a great functionality called `date_range`:

```
import pandas as pd

start_date ='2018-01-01T00:00:00'
end_date ='2018-01-31T23:59:59'
pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='1h')
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 02:00:00', '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 04:00:00', '2018-01-01 05:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 06:00:00', '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 08:00:00', '2018-01-01 09:00:00',
               ...
               '2018-01-31 14:00:00', '2018-01-31 15:00:00',
               '2018-01-31 16:00:00', '2018-01-31 17:00:00',
               '2018-01-31 18:00:00', '2018-01-31 19:00:00',
               '2018-01-31 20:00:00', '2018-01-31 21:00:00',
               '2018-01-31 22:00:00', '2018-01-31 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=744, freq='H')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
import datetime

start_date ='2018-01-01T00:00:00'
end_date ='2018-01-31T23:59:59'
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
while start<end: 
    start += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    print(start)
```

**The result:**

```
2018-01-01 01:00:00
2018-01-01 02:00:00
2018-01-01 03:00:00
2018-01-01 04:00:00
2018-01-01 05:00:00
.
.
.
2018-01-31 21:00:00
2018-01-31 22:00:00
2018-01-31 23:00:00
2018-02-01 00:00:00
```